# How can I protect my screen to be captured?

Tags: android, security, screen-capture

I have some screens in my app and I want it be prevented by being captured from other apps, due to some confidential info.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is a way provided by Android itself to disable screenshots, may be it can help.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

In your activity -

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: This will prevent screenshots and screenrecord from being able to see the layer.  (See also `SurfaceView#setSecure()`.)  It's worth mentioning that other apps do not have permission to capture your screen; only privileged users like `root` and `shell` can do so.  If your app is running on a rooted device, it's entirely possible that the graphics compositor has also been replaced and ignores the "secure" flag, so all bets are off.